# Pure JavaScript: Center an absolute position div in body

Tags: javascript, centering

What's the easiest and shortest way to center an absolute position div in the body without using a library like jQuery. Thank you!

Edit:
Something like http://jsfiddle.net/apfwh/ but maybe with a bit cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think no js needed. CSS will do it ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/mTYfe/)):

```
body {
    background: #888;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

**UPD**

In case you don't have fixed width/height of element:

JS (when element is opened):

```
element.style.margitLeft = -element.offsetWidth / 2
element.style.margitTop = -element.offsetHeight / 2
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    background: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: this is only if the width *and* height of the box is known

Comment: +1 this is super cool. However, I want the element to stay where it was opened, that's why javascript is needed.

Comment: What does "stay where it was opened" mean? Or just "opened" for that matter?

Comment: I'm trying to create Lighbox-like script from scratch and I want the Fancybox stay-where-it-was-first-opened behavior. (http://fancybox.net/blog)

Comment: So far I found that http://www.demtron.com/blog/post/2009/01/14/Centering-a-DIV-Window-with-Cross-Browser-JavaScript.aspx but it does not look like the best solution (http://jsfiddle.net/apfwh/).

Comment: @7elephant just change `position` to `fixed` that element will stays at the same place